# file upload functionality fails on production server

Tags: spring, file, upload, boot

I am using Spring Boot on Windows development environment with Java 1.8 open JDK 8.

File uploading functionality works fine on development environment. But, it does not work on production environment when I deploy the WAR file. My production environment has Apache tomcat 8.0.36, Java 1.8 open jdk 8, Ubuntu.

This is the web site :[www.samslisting.com](http://www.samslisting.com)

Below is the spring Boot code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SUB_CATEGORY_1_1_post", method = {  RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView categorypost(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("formData") SUB_CATEGORY_1_1 formData, 
            BindingResult bindingResult, 
            @RequestParam(value = "image",required = false) MultipartFile[] multipartFile,          
            HttpSession session, Model model) {
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        boolean imageNotUploaded = false;
        boolean unSupportedFileType = false;
        for(int i=0;i<multipartFile.length;i++)
        {   
            if(multipartFile[0].getOriginalFilename().equals(""))
            {
                imageNotUploaded = true;
            }
            if(!multipartFile[i].getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                String fileName = multipartFile[i].getOriginalFilename();
                String []fileNames = fileName.split("\\.");
                int fileNamesLength = fileNames.length;
                List <String > supportedFileTypes = new ArrayList<String >();
                    supportedFileTypes.add("apng");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("avif");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("gif");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("jpg");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("jpeg");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("jfif");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("pjpeg");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("pjp");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("png");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("svg");
                    supportedFileTypes.add("webp");
                if(supportedFileTypes.contains(fileNames[fileNamesLength-1].toLowerCase()) )
                {
                    
                }
                else {
                    unSupportedFileType = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || imageNotUploaded||unSupportedFileType) {
            HashMap<String, String> countrylist = null;
            try {
                countrylist = Common_List.getCountryList(dataSource.getConnection());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            if(imageNotUploaded) {
                modelAndView.addObject("error", "Please upload image!");
            }
            if(unSupportedFileType) {
                modelAndView.addObject("error1", "Please upload image of Type supported! "
                        + " .apng, .avif, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .jfif, .pjpeg, .pjp, .png, .svg, .webp ");
            }
            modelAndView.addObject("countrylist", countrylist);
             modelAndView.setViewName("SubCategory_1_1");
        }else {
            
            formData.setCATEGORY(SystemConstant.intCategory_1);
            formData.setSUB_CATEGORY(SystemConstant.intSubCategory_1_1);
            
            String caca = (String)session.getAttribute("USERID");
            
            formData.setUSERID(Long.parseLong(caca));
            formData = service.createOrUpdateUser(formData);
            
            for(int i=0;i<multipartFile.length;i++)
            {   
                if(!multipartFile[i].getOriginalFilename().equals(""))
                {
                        
                        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile[i].getOriginalFilename());
                        
                        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                        
                        String uploadDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +  "user-photos"+ File.separator + SystemConstant.intCategory_1+File.separator+ SystemConstant.intSubCategory_1_1+
                                File.separator+(String)session.getAttribute("USERID")+ File.separator+formData.getSUB_CATEGORY_1_1_ID();
                        Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
                        
                        if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
                            try {
                                Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                         
                        try  {
                            InputStream inputStream = multipartFile[i].getInputStream();
                            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
                            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            
                            IMAGES_1_1 image = new IMAGES_1_1();
                            image.setUSERID(formData.getUSERID());
                            image.setSUB_CATEGORY_1_1_ID(formData.getSUB_CATEGORY_1_1_ID());
                            image.setCATEGORY(SystemConstant.intCategory_1);
                            image.setSUB_CATEGORY(SystemConstant.intSubCategory_1_1);
                            image.setNAME(multipartFile[i].getOriginalFilename());
                            serviceImage.createOrUpdateImage(image);
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {        
                            try {
                                throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } 
                }
            
            }
            modelAndView.setViewName("SamList");
        }       
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: What error is coming in production environment ?

Comment: production environment does not throw any error. Just File is not getting uploaded.

Comment: ok how are you uploading file in production? Using POSTMAN or some other client?

Comment: I am uploading files through jsp page and here above is the backend code for it.

Comment: Ok. I can see multipartfile RequestParam is not mandatory in your controller. Can you please make it mandatory by setting required=true and also change value. It should be files.  Like this @RequestParam(value=“files”,required=“true”)

Comment: Error Solved. Problem was in file path location. Characters are not case sensitive on windows where as they are case sensitive on Linux Systems in file path name.

Comment: Good to know that error solved :)